# How to handle wild characters in Macros?

Tags: vba, excel

I have wrote a piece of code to replace any characters, but it doesn't work fine with `*`. Can some one guide how I can handle `*`.
Here is the code:

```
nextrow = ActiveCell.Row
tocolnbr = ActiveCell.Column
Columns(tocolnbr).Select

Selection.Replace What:="'", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to replace, it looks like you just want to replace an apostrophe with a blank

Comment: I am trying to replace "*" with blank. This code works with every character except *.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `~` [tilde as per Office Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214138).

> Microsoft Excel uses the tilde (~) as a marker to indicate that the next character is a literal. When you use the Find and Replace dialog box to find or replace a character such as a tilde (~), an asterisk (*), or a question mark (?), you must add a tilde (~) before the character in the Find what box.

So it must be something like this:

```
Selection.Replace What:="~*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it's Chr value

```
Selection.Replace What:=Chr(42), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
```

**EDIT:**
I posted without checking.  Your code works to replace "*" with nothing, although what you posted is replacing "'" with nothing.

Comment: I have tried this what you posted but it does not work. Thanks

Comment: Is the correct range being selected?  To test I manually selected my column and stepped through the code.

Answer (score 0):

I just used this,

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("K2")
    rng = Replace(rng, "*", "")
End Sub
```

And it removed the *

Is it a Character? Or just an asterix?

For an entire range of cells,

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Set rng = Range("K2:K20")
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        c = Replace(c, "*", "")
    Next c
End Sub
```

I have seen on some occasions where you would have to use the tilde "`" symbol but I don't know if is required here.