# Find text that contains tilde character

Tags: excel, vba

When I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find `WLR2~LW~VBD_MPN`, it does not show up.

Using a simple example, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> finds words like `cwfwf` and `qwdqw`.

`WLR2~LW~VBD_MPN` can be found on other software—including other Office products—such as Microsoft Word.

I tried ticking/unticking options like *match case* and *match entire cell contents* as well as also other options (within/search/lookin).

What can be done to find a word like `WLR2~LW~VBD_MPN`?

Further clarification: `WLR2~LW~VBD_MPN` is not created by any formulas.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857051/how-to-handle-wild-characters-in-macros  You need to search for `WLR2~~LW~~VBD_MPN`  Tilde has a special meaning, so you need to escape it with another tilde.

Comment: @TimWilliams ah thanks alot...