# How can I remove the caracter * on vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to remove a value that contains a special character *** <-

I tried

the find and replace, but when I put the * character
all the cells are cleaned

I did this code to, but nothing happens, how can I do that ?

```
Sub removeSpecialCharacter()

Dim x As Integer
Dim special_value As String
x = 1
Range("a2").Select

 let special_value = activecell.offset(0, 0).value

    Do
        'trying to remove ***
        If special_value = "***" Then
           special_value = ""
        End If

        x = x + 1
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select


    Loop Until x = 100

End Sub
```

Thanks guys that's really helped me

```
 Selection.Replace What:="~*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: use `~*` to replace asterik.

Comment: This question already has been asked and answered [How to handle wild characters in macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857051/how-to-handle-wild-characters-in-macros)

Comment: Thanks guys that's really helped me

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub StarKiller()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Range("A2:A100")
        For Each r In rng
            If r.Value = Chr(42) Then
                r.Value = ""
            End If
        Next r
End Sub
```