# Replace all * in a selected row with x

Tags: excel, vba

I've made a script to import a bunch of what are essentially .txt files, which describe a steel beam, into their own columns so I can manipulate/rename them as a batch and export them out again.

However Im having trouble with special characters in file names.

This is what my data look like;

```
ST
** R1013.nc1
  23SJ220
  R1013
  2
  R1013
  300
  1
  PFC230*75
  U
       5678
        230
         75
         12
          6
         12
       25.1
        0.7
```

I need to separate them into different folders for processing. The problem Im having is in line 9 `PFC230*75` in this case. I cant name a folder `PFC230*75` So I need something to replace all "*"  in the row with "x".

I've tried a bunch of different examples I've found, such as;

```
Sub AHT_NAME()
Dim Findtext As String
Dim Replacetext As String
Findtext = Range("M2").Value
Replacetext = Range("I2").Value
Cells.replace What:=Findtext, Replacement:=Replacetext, LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

However this has had the effect of replacing the entire contents of the cell with "x"

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle wild characters in Macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857051/how-to-handle-wild-characters-in-macros)

Comment: I think it would have, however I ended up solving it with this;

'''
Sub TextReplace_to_x()
Dim sheetName As String
Dim findText As String
Dim replaceText As String
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim lCol As Long
sheetName = "data1"

lastCol = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
origString = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(9, 1).Value
For lCol = 1 To lastCol

    findText = "x"
    replaceText = "*"
    origString = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(9, lCol)
    Sheets(sheetName).Cells(9, lCol) = Replace(origString, findText, replaceText)
Next lCol
End Sub
'''

Comment: I dont know how to format the comment better sorry :/

Comment: You cannot format multi-line code in a comment. If you would like to answer your own question, then simply add an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Ahh, Good to know, thanks!